# Correct way to terminate a postgres replication mode connection

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I have the following code that enables logical decoding in PostgreSQL 9.4:

```
pg_recvlogical -h localhost --slot test_slot --create-slot
pg_recvlogical -h localhost --slot test_slot --start -f -
```

I spawn a node.js subprocess to run this code and listen for changes however I'm unsure of what the correct procedure is to terminate the connection. I usually just `CNTRL+C` from the command line or kill the subprocess in code but I always get a `pg_recvlogical: unexpected termination of replication stream:` error. What is the correct way to terminate this connection?

Comment: you dont want to  `pg_recvlogical -h localhost --slot test_slot --drop-slot`?..

Comment: That kills the slot - I only want to terminate a connection to it.

Comment: if you cant send SIGINT to process with `--start -f`, you probably have to kill it ny pid?..

Comment: In code, I use a 'SIGINT' signal to terminate the process however I still get the same error.

Comment: ah - sorry. I get it now - you want to suppress the notice

Answer (score 2):

The [PostgreSQL documentation says](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/app-pgrecvlogical.html),

> --start
>      Begin streaming changes from the logical replication slot specified by --slot, continuing until terminated by a signal. If the server side change stream ends with a server shutdown or disconnect, retry in a loop unless --no-loop is specified.

So I assume the standard Linux signals meanings apply. Therefore, `SIGINT` or `SIGQUIT` should be acceptable, giving the app time to finish.

What I do is I send `SIGINT`, then enter a loop, check if `/proc/$PID_/stat` exists, and after custom timeout, I send it `SIGKILL`, and `wait $PID_` for it.

```
kill -2 $PID_
for i in `seq 1 8`; do
    if [ ! -f /proc/$PID_/stat ] ; then
        RETURN_CODE=`wait $PID_`;
        break;
    fi
    sleep 1;
done
if [ -f /proc/$PID_/stat ] ; then
    kill -9 $PID_;
    RETURN_CODE=`wait $PID_`;
fi
```

This is Bash, but any decent platform/language will have tools to do it.
Shortened, so there may be a bug :)

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to kill a zombie active replication slot.

> 1. connect to the server where postgres is installed using CLI with ssh.

```
ssh -i <generated_security_key_name/path>.pem <username>@<hostIp>
```

> 2. once connected with the VM in your server. type following command to connect to postgres sql.

```
sudo -i -u <postgres-username>
```

> 3. you can go with psql which is a terminal-based front-end to PostgreSQL

```
psql
```

> 4. check the pid against your replication slot.

```
select * from pg_replication_slots;
```

> Enter the following to kill it.

```
sudo kill <pid>
```